# Can I use music I made in GarageBand or FL Studio in a commercial game?

Tags: legal, music, licensing

I'm a beginning developer and I'd like to make music for my game. I've searched this question on the site, and when it comes to music in games, I see many people suggesting programs like *FL Studio*, *Reaper*, *GarageBand*, etc.

What are the legal implications of using music made with them in a commercial game? Is it okay to use music I've created on my computer with one of these programs (I was thinking of FL Studio) in a game I plan to profit from?

Comment: There are usually forums dedicated to more popular packages like the ones you described - so you could also ask there: they would definitely be able to give you a more authoritative answer than we can.

Comment: What would be the point for that program to exist if you couldn't use the files it generates?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the licensing terms of specific software, best answered by the software's EULA or its developers.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know: as long as you **pay for the software** (not pirate it by, for example, downloading it via bit torrents) you can use it.
However, for example, if in GarageBand you use existing audio loops/samples, you may have to check for clearance with the creator or owner of the rights to the samples.

Comment: He could check the license agreement - but I know for a fact that FL Studio, Reaper and Reason are royalty-free. I think basically any package used by any serious producer would be royalty-free (thus including ProLogic too).

Comment: For the software, yes, however i was referring to the samples, sounds and loops that come with them.

Comment: Indeed. I also know that the samples included with FL Studio are royalty-free, as well as any of the official sample packs that you an purchase on their website. The license is usually easy to find with these things - so you might want to add he could try and find the license for any samples he is using. If they are royalty-free they usually have a big banner or something; because it's a marketing point.

Comment: Here's some information regarding garage-band: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2931